# Symmetric Difference in graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I was studying some text in graph theory, and I found this problem which I can't solve, I came here to ask for some help.

Let $S := \{x_1, x_2, . . . , x_n\}$ be an $n$-set, and let $A := \{A_1,A_2, . . . , A_n\}$ be
a family of n distinct subsets of $S$.

Construct a graph $G$ with vertex set $A$, two
vertices $A_i$ and $A_j$ being joined by an edge if their symmetric difference $A_i\triangle A_j$
is a singleton. Label the edge $A_iA_j$ by this singleton. By studying this labelled
graph, prove that there is an element $x_m∈ S$ such that the sets $A_1\cup\{x_m\},A_2 \cup
\{x_m\}, . . . , A_n \cup \{x_m\}$ are distinct.

There is a hint that says "show that $G$ has a spanning forest with the same set of labels as $G$", but if such forest, $F$, does exist, doesn't that mean that $F=G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what would happen if for all elements $x_m$, two of the sets $A_i \cup \{x_m \}$ and $A_j \cup \{x_m \}$ were identical? For starters, $A_i\triangle A_j$ must equal $x_m$ (since we know $A_i$ and $A_j$ are distinct), so there must be at least one edge with label $x_m$ in your graph $G$. For simplicity, let's pick exactly one of these edges to include in $G$ (and we will ignore the rest).

Now, this is true for every element $x_m$, so we have $n$ edges in $G$, each labelled with a different label. But $G$ has $n$ vertices, so if it has $n$ edges, it must have a cycle! Let's say this cycle contains an edge labelled with $x_0$. Note then that since no other edge is labelled with $x_0$, removing this edge must cut the component it belongs to into two pieces; one containing sets containing $x_0$ and one containing sets lacking $x_0$. However, this edge is part of a cycle, so removing it does not partition the vertices in its component into two sets, thus leading to a contradiction.